# accessing different servers (urls) using selenium ide

Tags: url, firefox, selenium-ide

I've a requirement to hit a url of server x, click a submit button and jump to same url of server y and click the same submit button and this has to be repeated 26 times as I've to change on 26 servers.

All this I have to do selenium ide. I managed to do this for 1 server but just wondering if there is a smart way to do this for 26 servers rather recording 26 times.

I'm using selenium 2.9.0 IDE plugin with firefox browser

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="selenium.base" href="http://server-x:9173/" />
    <title>New Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
    </thead><tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>website/delivery/DeliveryMethodsRepository/</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>link=DeliveryMethodsRepository/</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>link=invalidateCaches</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>name=submit</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>link=DeliveryMethodsRepository/</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
    </thead><tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>open</td>
        <td>inventory/InventoryRepository/</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>link=InventoryRepository/</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>link=invalidateCaches</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>name=submit</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>link=InventoryRepository/</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep base url as "http://". You then need to use readCSV for all server urls and while loop for repeating for number of servers.

Please refer [http://bashamy.blogspot.co.uk/2016/01/selenium-ide-to-use-while-loop-and-read.html] for more information.

Edit Url: http://bashamy.blogspot.com/2016/01/selenium-ide-to-use-while-loop-and-read.html

Eg: Below html code opens 5 different urls from my CSV input file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://onlineconversion.com/" />
<title>06 ReadCsv_n_Loop</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">06 ReadCsv_n_Loop</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>readCSV</td>
    <td>file://C:\Users\extayx\Documents\Selenium IDE\07Input.csv</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>row</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>col</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>z</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>${row}&lt;${z}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeCellValue</td>
    <td>ip</td>
    <td>${row},${col}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${ip}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>${ip}</td>
    <td>${ip}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['row'] = ${row}+1</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>endWhile</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

My input CSV file has below information.

```
www.google.co.in
www.google.com
www.google.co.uk
www.news.google.co.in
www.seleniumhq.org
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer.   I'll try this tomorrow and let you know.  The link shared by you is dead.  Could you please check and paste the correct link?  Thanks again.

Comment: http://bashamy.blogspot.com/2016/01/selenium-ide-to-use-while-loop-and-read.html

Please check the url. You need to add user extension js in your Selenium IDE

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very confusing, so I probably misunderstood it.
In the unlikely case I got it right, you're trying to do the same task for different websites 26 times. Sounds like something a loop could do.
Here's a sample Python code:

```
urls = ['http://foo.bar', 'http://otherfoo.otherbar',...]
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    #your selenium code here
```

Comment: Not sure which part of my question is confusing you. I'm familiar with java and I could write this logic in java. The problem is I'm unable to import the modified java code into selenium IDE. After browsing for a while I came to know, it is not possible to port .java or .py files into selenium IDE and it accepts only .html files. If you have modified the same on html files, please pass on to me. Thanks and Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Whelp apparently I've lost my reading skills. I completely missed the IDE part and thought you referred to a the framework, sorry! Anyway you might have already found that but this seems promising: http://www.testingdiaries.com/selenium-ide-loop/

Answer (score 1):

This is something I have had to do myself, and is possible using a set of plugins called [selite](http://selite.github.io/) or also selblocks (although selite contains a version of this plugin already)

With these plugins it will allow you to save the list of URLs as an external json file, then to loop the test case you will just need to put the 'Forjson' command calling the file at the stage where you want your loop to begin, and the 'Endforjson' where you want it to end. All the documentation is in the link. Hope it helps.