# Access the same Popup window with different Test Cases with Selenium IDE

Tags: firefox, selenium, popup, selenium-ide

I'm trying to create a Test Suite with a few Test Cases to build a 'modular' test for my application. The application has some features that can be reused many times. It's like a puzzle that could be mounted in many formats. For instance, the application has some parts that are shared by some products and some parts that are shared by other products.

My problem is to access the same popup window in different test cases.
For example:

```
Test Suite Product 1 
Case A (Login)
Case B (Fill some fields and open popup)
Case C (Fill some pages at Popup window)
Case D (Fill more pages at Popup window)
Case E (Get results and close application)

Test Suite Product 2
Case A (Login)
Case Z (Fill different fields and open popup)
Case C (Fill some pages at Popup window)
Case X (Fill different pages at Popup window)
Case E (Get results and close application)

Test Suite Product 3
Case A (Login)
Case B (Fill some fields and open popup)
Case C (Fill some pages at Popup window)
Case X (Fill different pages at Popup window)
Case E (Get results and close application)
```

And so on...

I read already about creating rollup scripts and using only 1 test case for each Product Option. But I couldn't find a good Editor to create and edit these rollup scripts. I'm using the IDE version of Selenium because the facility to record the actions. Some parts of our application has more than 100 Yes/No medical questions divided in many pages and it can be changed depending on which product the client is accessing.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I've tried some things, but with no luck so far.
Seeing the logs it seems that the IDE loses any completely the popup id that was created, and without this, it's not possible for it to focus on the popup.
I tried to put selectPopUp, waitForPopUp, selectWindow, all with no success.

If I debug the test or click on the popup window before the timeout and bring the focus to it "manually", the test continues with no errors. But it's not a proper solution.

**Update2:**

Looking the logs, I could see that the windows id (seleniumXXXXXXXXXX) changes completely after finishing a test case and starting a new one. It seems that the Selenium creates a whole new poll of windows, but considering only the original window and forgetting the new pop up(s) that was(were) created during the test case...

No one is having the same issue? No one has any information to help??

Comment: can you refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493144/accessing-different-servers-urls-using-selenium-ide/34565590#34565590 and see whether you can implement this? Here it will be one test case.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @AbdulHameed, but It's not what I need. This is to open different urls. In my case, I'm in the same Struts session and the url could change a bit depending on which submit button was pressed at last page from last case. I couldn't store the url in a CSV or any other file, because it's dynamic.

Comment: Looking at the logs I could see that every new case the IDE restart the Poll of Windows (or something like) and, because of this, for some reason, it can't find the popup again... Calling the `storeAllWindowName` before the end of a test case brings all pages, including the popup. If I call the same action at the beginning of the next test case it brings only the main window, ignoring the popup... It always calls the `createForWindow` action. `[info] Test case passed
[info] Playing test case Emulate Broker
[debug] createForWindow`

Comment: you can reuse variables between test cases that run in the same test suite. You can take advantage of this to store the window ID, although I think that might be buggy in the ide currently.